# SQL Server: Select Top X Rows file location

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know where the file that contain the query for `"Select Top X Rows"`?  I have looked in the registry for `"Select Top"` and `"/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/"`.  I have searched on the C:\ drive for those two items as well and I have come up with nothing.

I am NOT looking for `SSMS --> Tools --> SQL Server Object Explorer --> Commands`.  I am looking for the code that runs that.  I want to edit that code.

Comment: `SELECT TOP(n) ....` is the way to go - isn't that working for you? What are you looking for then, if not `SELECT TOP(n) ...` ??

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying you want to edit the logic for the sql engine works with select top???

Comment: He maybe looking for the templates when right clicking on a table and clicking on "Select top 1000 rows".  As fas as I know you are unable to edit this query/template.  You are able to edit other templates, they are located (windows 7) here C:\Users\ user name \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Templates\Sql

Comment: All signs point to 'no', as in it appears you can't. But to verify, you could use Process Monitor (from SysInternals) to monitor all files opened by SSMS.  Almost certainly it's built-in functionality, though.